# Error: nested select statement: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, plsql

I am trying to fetch results from a query like:

```
Select abc, def,

     (Select distinct ghi from table1 where condition1, condition2)
    From table1
    Where condition3, condition4.
```

It throws the error: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: Then you probably have duplicates in table1 even with your conditions.  Please show a REAL sql statement, sample table data.

Comment: Yes that is right. Is there any way to get all the rows returned by the subquery along with the other columns? The actual query and data is too big.

Comment: not with a subquery.  maybe a left join but since you don't show sample data and expected output, really can't say.  You can edit your question and add that w/o a query.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.